# How to determine if a matrix $B$ is spanned by $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a matrix $B$, how do I determine if it is spanned by $V$?

For example:

Let $B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2\\ 
0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$

$V = \mathrm{span} \left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0 \\ 
0&1 
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
1&2 \\ 
0&0 
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0 \\ 
3&0
\end{bmatrix}
\right \}$

What is the linear combination in $V$, that is used to produced $B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** You want to check whether the equation 
$$
\pmatrix{1&2\\ 0&3} = a_1 \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} + 
a_2 \pmatrix{1&2\\0&0} + 
a_3 \pmatrix{0&0\\3&0}
$$
has a solution for $a_1,a_2,a_3$.  Remember that two matrices are equal if and only if all of their entries coincide.

Noting that the bottom-right entry of the matrix must be $0$, we can see that any solution must satisfy $a_3 = 0$.

Comment: I'm sorry but the last matrix is 0,0,3,0 and not 0,0,3,1

Comment: Okay, that doesn't change much